# By what mechanism does the Google Maps mobile app determine if a device is in one of the "limited locations" which has motorcycle directions?

Tags: google-maps

Sometimes, Google Maps for mobile (iOS and Android app) has directions available for scooters / motorcycles (called "two wheelers" by google). This is useful in cities like Taipei that have certain routes that are available only for these vehicles, and illegal for cars to go on, or, have routes that it's illegal for "two wheelers" to go on. These routes can sometimes differ significantly, thus the option is basically necessary to use google maps in certain cities for navigation.

According to [Google Support](https://support.google.com/maps/answer/11473680?hl=en), "This feature is only available for mobile devices and in limited locations."

On most of my mobile devices, this option is available when I open the Google Maps app and am physically present in Taiwan. For example, Pixel 4a5g, Galaxy S10, Galaxy Zfold3. Some of these devices weren't purchased in Taiwan, which makes me believe the app simply detects through the GPS antenna whether the phone is physically present in an area that has the "two wheeler" navigation option available.

However, some devices don't have the option, despite being physically present in Taiwan. For example, a Unihertz Atom XL device doesn't have the option (despite following online advice regarding uninstalling, clearing cache, logging out / in, etc).

I've been unable to determine if there's some way to "force" the Google Maps app to acknowledge that the device is present in a location that clearly has the "two wheeler" navigation option available. Neither Google Support nor Unihertz support seems aware if it's Google's, or the phone manufacturer's, responsibility in determining whether the option will be available in the Google Maps app (I was thinking perhaps there was a flag the manufacturer needed to toggle in Android or Google Play Services or something).

So, via what mechanism does the Google Maps app determine if it should show the motorcycle directions option? Is this mechanism controlled by Google, a phone manufacturer, or someone else? My goal is to consistently have access to the motorcycle option in available locations, is that possible?

EDIT: Note that per [support](https://support.google.com/maps/thread/177434046/my-motorcycle-mode-is-gone-how-to-bring-it-back?hl=en), the motorcycle directions may only be available to "Play Protect certified" devices, which includes Unihertz devices.